# How to insert value into primary key identity column in SQL through C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

(My problem solved. As almost everyone said I had to remove @OB_ID and left it to SQL to assign value.)

I want to insert a new record into a table in SQL database through C# code. The primary key is identity. How can I make Visual Studio understood that the column is identity so SQL Server must set the value. Here's the related code:

```
SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection();
sqlc.ConnectionString = "Data Source=. ; Database=LDatabase; Integrated Security=true;";

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Order_Book VALUES(@OB_ID, @OB_Title, @OB_Author, @OB_TranslatedBy, @OB_Publisher)", sqlc);//@OB_ID is indentity primary key
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_ID", );//What should I assign to it?
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Title", "%" + txtboxbook.Text + "%");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Author", "%" + txtboxAuthor.Text + "%");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_TranslatedBy", "%" + txtboxTranslator.Text + "%");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Publisher", "%" + txtboxPublisher.Text + "%");
            sqlc.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlc.Close();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to add anything. Remove `@OB_ID` and SQL Server will know to add the next key in sequence.

Comment: I did so. This is the error I recieved: " Must declare the scalar variable "@OB_ID""

Comment: Remove the @OB_ID also from the SQL Command text

Comment: As @Steve said, you need to remove ALL references to it. SQL Server will take care of it. See my answer for an example.

Comment: As a side note, what is the purpose of the % wildcard in an INSERT statement?

Comment: @Steve %[string]%: it means this is a series of Unicode characters

Comment: @Behnaz_Mardanzadeh Do you have a reference for that?  Because I am unaware of any such convention being implemented by either T-SQL or ADO.net.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'll try to find the reference I adopted from. Let me take a look.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Sorry I couldn't find the reference. Once I got into a website abt that on internet. Now I can't find it.

Comment: @Steve I noticed that % sign was inserted into database. I removed it and the code is still working OK so forget about what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can ignore `IDENTITY` column as it will be inserted `by default`.

Try This

```
SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection();
sqlc.ConnectionString = "Data Source=. ; Database=LDatabase; Integrated Security=true;";
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Order_Book VALUES(@OB_Title, @OB_Author, @OB_TranslatedBy, @OB_Publisher)", sqlc);//@OB_ID is indentity primary key

cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Title", "%" + txtboxbook.Text + "%");
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Author", "%" + txtboxAuthor.Text + "%");
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_TranslatedBy", "%" + txtboxTranslator.Text + "%");
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Publisher", "%" + txtboxPublisher.Text + "%");
sqlc.Open();
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add anything as SQL Server will automatically increment and assign the Identity field. So, simply remove `@OB_ID` and SQL Server will know to add the next key in sequence, so...

```
SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection();
sqlc.ConnectionString = "Data Source=. ; Database=LDatabase; Integrated Security=true;";

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Order_Book VALUES(@OB_Title, @OB_Author,     @OB_TranslatedBy, @OB_Publisher)", sqlc);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Title", "%" + txtboxbook.Text + "%");
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Author", "%" + txtboxAuthor.Text + "%");
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_TranslatedBy", "%" + txtboxTranslator.Text + "%");
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Publisher", "%" + txtboxPublisher.Text + "%");
        sqlc.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You souldn't put the id in your request. SQLServer will add the good identity at insertion.

```
SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection();
sqlc.ConnectionString = "Data Source=. ; Database=LDatabase; Integrated Security=true;";

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Order_Book VALUES( @OB_Title,    @OB_Author, @OB_TranslatedBy, @OB_Publisher)", sqlc);//@OB_ID is indentity primary key
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Title", "%" + txtboxbook.Text + "%");
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Author", "%" + txtboxAuthor.Text + "%");
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_TranslatedBy", "%" + txtboxTranslator.Text +  "%");
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OB_Publisher", "%" + txtboxPublisher.Text + "%");
        sqlc.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace Following**

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Order_Book VALUES( @OB_Title,    @OB_Author, @OB_TranslatedBy, @OB_Publisher)", sqlc);
//@OB_ID is indentity primary key
```

**With**

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Order_Book ON;INSERT INTO Order_Book VALUES( @OB_Title,    @OB_Author, @OB_TranslatedBy, @OB_Publisher);SET IDENTITY_INSERT Order_Book OFF;", sqlc);
 //@OB_ID is indentity primary key
```

Comment: Thanks. I got my problem solved. But I keep your solution in my mind. Seems very handy.